# input password and :after pseudoelement text

Tags: css, input

I have an HTML password input. I am using an :after pseudoelement on the password put field to display an error message to the user using content: "Invalid password".

However, the text that is displayed in the psuedoelement is all asterisks since it is a password field. If I change it to a text field it displays fine. Is there anyway to make the pseudoelement display straight text?

Comment: That's creative. Is there any reason you need to do this in CSS instead of using Javascript or server side code?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible to show text in password type input. You can change input type by JavaScript and after user focus change it back or create clone input textfield and changing on focus, but neither solution is good.